# Selenium Headers in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, cookies, header

how can I change my headers in Selenium like I do in requests
,I want to change my cookies and headers .

```
from myCookie import cookie
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time


headers = {
"Host": "mbasic.facebook.com",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; en-us; SCH-I535 Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30",
"Accept": "image/avif,image/webp,*/*",
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
'Accept-Encoding': '',
'Alt-Used': 'https://mbasic.facebook.com/',
'Connection': "keep-alive",
'Cookie': cookie,
}


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.fb.com")
# how can I update driver with my cookies and this headers
```

Comment: Did you do ANY research on this yourself?  A web search on "python selenium cookies" returns lots of hits...

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.add_cookie({"name": cookie_name, "value": cookie_value})
```

Comment: @Mokhtaromar This answer gives you the exact code for setting a cookie.  I don't understand what more are you are asking for.

Comment: I have a netscap cookie i get it from network in my local driver , I want to add it in selenium