# selenium headers cookies python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, python-requests

how can I make a request with selenium that change my headers and cookies

I want to do the same request but by selenium :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import time


# my cookie
cookie = "example awdawawdawdawdadawdaplw,d;awdawd;lawd,awda;wdawd"
header = {
"Host": "mbasic.facebook.com",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; en-us; SCH-I535 Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30",
"Accept": "image/avif,image/webp,*/*",
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
'Accept-Encoding': '',
'Alt-Used': 'https://mbasic.facebook.com/',
'Connection': "keep-alive",
'Cookie': cookie,
}

ses = requests.Session()
ses.headers.update(header)
```

i don't know where can i get cookies except the network section in inspect

Comment: This seems identical to your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76544248/494134)...

Comment: I just think my question it's not clear :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium Headers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76544248/selenium-headers-in-python)